# DOMParser().parseFromString() can't parse <p> element correctly

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

I've encountered an issue when using `DOMParser` API. I noticed that it parses the `<p>` tag incorrectly.

```
var myHtml = '<p><span><div>Hello</div></span><div>World</div></p>'
const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHtml, 'text/html');

// parsed is:
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p></p>
  <span><div>Hello</div></span>
  <div>World</div>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there's something wrong with the structure. If you switch `<p>` tag with e.g. `<span>` it'll work just fine. What's the issue here? Is there a specific case in the spec for `parseFromString` method that is the reason?

Comment: Paragraphs can not contain block level elements, so the parser closes the paragraph before the first div. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p): *'Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing </p> tag.'*

Comment: @Seblor yep. It does. As well as the first comment to this post (from @pilchard).